# Chrome limits simultaneous connections to a domain even if the request is cached

Tags: google-chrome, caching, web

**Background:**

There seems to be a consensus that current versions of Chrome have a domain level concurrent connection limit of 6-10 (I'm having trouble finding specific documentation about the exact limit)

**My specific problem:**

I'm working on an application that displays a large number of scatter plots to a user, rendered as `.png` images. When the user makes a GET request for a specific image, the server dynamically generates the image and returns it. Sometimes this can take a long time (>10 seconds).

I've set the appropriate `cache-control` headers and can see that previously generated images are being correctly retrieved from the disk cache, and checking from my web server side, no GET request is being made to the server:

[image: Cached GET request for .png]

However I get into trouble when the user navigates back to a page of cached images while there are currently 10+ active GET requests for images currently waiting. Even though images are in the disk cache, they still get queued / stalled anyway:

[image: Disk cached image is stalled]

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way around this - I've thought about a number of different solutions including cancelling image requests part way, and creating a proxy server that listens on multiple subdomains or ports (i.e. `image1.foo.com`, `image2.foo.com`), but it just seems strange to me that Chrome would be designed in a way that even images cached from the disk are queued behind images that are requested remotely.

Just thought I'd mention that I could also have made a mistake in my implementation that is causing something to go wrong, so please let me know if it sounds like there's something else funky going on.

EDIT: I've since verified that this behaviour occurs even when serving images over HTTP2. I initially suspected the concurrent connection limit because it only applies over HTTP 1.1 (All the image requests should be made in parallel over the same TCP connection in HTTP2), but it seems that there's some kind of inbuilt concurrent image request limit that is independent of the number of outstanding HTTP requests (which makes sense given the previous behaviour with the disk cache)

Comment: I am having exact same problem and i am clueless about possible solutions.. Did you come up with something?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you may have to find your own distinct solution. I solved my probably by having my server return `201 Accepted` rather than 200 when requesting an image that wasn't ready, then using `setInterval` to re check if it had completed rendering server side.